# No HTML/Visual mode option in admin panel (New Post)

Tags: wp-admin

There is no option for switching  html to visual mode in add new post page of my admin panel

there is no js error in console
reinstalled WP from WP updates admin panel too, 
and there are no 404 on any js file either

home page url is http://bankpo.in

couldnt upload image so giving a link for screenshot

http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/3476/clipboard02lr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**Turn off all your plugins... then check it. if its all good

(what would probably be true) start activating your plugins

on at a time to find the problem maker.**

This happened to me several times and in 9/10 cases was a plugin...

the 1/10 time was a nasty code i pasted into my functions.php so if 
turning off your plugins doesn't work activate error report temporary

**by changing:**

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

**To:**

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

And paste in your questions the error or if you can fix them
and the try again...

Hope this helps ;)
Cheers, Sagive.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Users -> Your Profile** and make sure that "Disable the visual editor when writing" isn't ticked.